# What is the difference between the interval in Qt.timer start() and the setInterval

Tags: python, pyqt

My program works. But I have a hard time differentiating between `start()` and `setInterval` in `Qt.QTimer()`. An explanation will be appreciated.

```
self.timer= Qt.QTimer()        
self.timer.setInterval(TICK_TIME)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick) 

and

self.timer.start(1)
```

Comment: I'm no PyQt-ist, but in C++, the two are equivalent and interchangeable. PyQt is probably similar.

Comment: `start ([interval])` 
Starts the timer. In the optional parameter, you can specify a time interval in milliseconds. If the parameter is not specified, the value returned by the `interval ()` method is used.